# How to handle Null Props in React's Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a form, so a typical form will have edit and create, I have no problem for create, which the existing data is passed from main container, and each component take it through props and assign to their own states like so

```
export default class Name extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const { data } = props

    this.state = {
      name: data.name
    }
  }

  ...
  ...
}
```

How ever I have problem with create, above code will have error if `<Name />` is render without data props. How to solve this issue? I can do

```
this.state = {
    name: data && data.name
}
```

but imagine I have other fields it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Use default prop?

Comment: pls check the answer below, hope it helps you and clarify this concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you *can set the* **props value as default values using defaultProps**:-

```
    export default class Name extends Component {
      static defaultProps = {
            name: "name default value",
            email: "email default value"  
          };

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
             name: this.props.name,
             email: this.props.email,
             // some other variables

            };
          }
...... ..........
...... ..........
}
```

or

you can update your props value in **componentWillReceiveProps()** method, this method will execute every time your props value changes either coming from Server or something. like below:-

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!this.props.name && nextProps.name) {
     // here you can do according to your need
     // you can update the values of variables in state here 

    this.setState({ name: nextProps.name });

    }
  }
```